# how to log with request context information in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, distributed-tracing

I have a Quarkus service, and would like to log with DataDog trace id for distributed tracing. The trace id is from the request header and differs per request.

In the current setup, I have singleton logger in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, for example,

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooServiceImpl.class);

  # error occurred, LOG.error("xxx")
```

How can I inject the request header and use it to enrich my log message?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry

Answer (score 0):

- You can attempt to inject the `HttpServerRequest` bean.

```java
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@RequestScoped
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

  @Inject Logger logger;
  @Context HttpServerRequest httpRequest;

  @Override
  public String foo() {
    httpRequest.headers().forEach((key, value) -> {
      logger.debug("Header: " + key + " = " + value);
    });
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

- Another approach is to create a filter class that implements `ContainerRequestFilter`.

```java
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@Provider
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Inject Logger logger;

  public RequestFilter() {}

  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    containerRequestContext
        .getHeaders()
        .forEach(
            (key, value) -> {
              logger.debug("Header: " + key + " = " + value);
            });
  }
}
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#request-or-response-filters

Comment: in your first example, I noticed you changed my original `@ApplicationScoped` to be `@RequestScoped` for FooServiceImpl, was that deliberate?

I tried to inject the   `@Context` HttpServerRequest httpRequest into my `@ApplicationScoped` beans, for example, the class dealing with database queries, and it gives 500 error during the runtime.

Comment: The HttpServerRequest is a request-scoped bean, and I believe it should be used in a @RequestScope service because the HttpServerRequest is specific to each individual HTTP request.
The error 500 could be caused by a mismatch in the lifecycles between the beans and the context. Please check the logs for the exception that is causing the error in order to further debug the issue.

Comment: @GeauxEric, you can only inject JAXRS resources in JAXRS beans, which are annotated with \@Path. ApplicationScoped is a CDI scope, not JAXRS.